# Restore of Raspberry Backup

Tags: backup

I tried this backup script described in another question
["A working script from the Raspberry Community made by a member there"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself/5431#5431), it runs with "pv" and "dd", but I was not able to properly restore it on another SD-card.

Is there a description how to restore it?

Best regards, Maverick

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used that script<sup>1</sup>, but it looks like it duplicates both partitions into an `.img` file, then tar & gzips that.  To extract the `.img`:

```
tar -xzf whatever.tar.gz
```

You can then mount and work with the partitions in the image following [the instructions here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image/13138#13138).  You can also use the `.img` to create an SD card following [these instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13119/first-time-rpi-user-raspberrian-installer-wont-boot-red-light-only/13121#13121).

**Note that you should not copy stuff from the second partition wholesale into a running system because: *A)* it will fail at certain points (`/proc`, `/sys`) -- hopefully; *B)* it will overwrite stuff in `/run`, `/var`, etc. that will likely screw up the system in very noticeable ways.**

---

<sup>1. Because my answer to that question makes more sense ;) Once implemented, it's faster, easier, and safer (since if you use that backup image the wrong way, you will screw up your system as explained above). I explain other reasons there why `dd` is NOT a good tool for the purpose of maintaining a backup.  I also explain how to *restore* from a (proper) backup using `rsync`...</sup>

Comment: I could have searched for the link myself, I was trying to get the original questioner to provide some details so that someone could answer his question. Your suggestion about `rsync` seems sensible, but is too complex for most beginners - who tend to be those who ask these questions. In fact the posted script below is misleading, as it is just a more complex way of running dd. In fact I "backup" my Pi using dd (and a script of my own) on another machine. If I need to go back it is just a case of mounting the image and copying needed files.

Comment: @Milliways : I can't see that answer as "too complex" for a beginner; it's just plain not complex. I don't quite explain every detail, true -- I refer to *globs* and *mount points* without defining them -- but these can easily be looked up or asked about, and they are things so elementary that if you are a beginner of some sort, you're going to have to learn what they refer to soon *if you are going to learn anything at all*.  Someone who can't or won't learn anything is unlikely to have wanted a pi in the first place...