# Can you use a micro SD card from raspberry pi B+ on the raspberry pi 2 model B?

Tags: sd-card, pi-2

Can you use a micro SD card from raspberry pi B+ on the raspberry pi 2 model B?

Comment: I'd suggest an edit: obviously one can use micro SD cards both on the B+ and model 2 (as they both use micro SD cards). The question here should emphasize more on the OS on that card (which is of course intended and already answered as such ;) )

Answer (score 5):

You will need a new kernel, which should be installed on Raspbian regardless of model (meaning, you can do it on the B+) if you:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the Pi 2 then fails to boot but produces kernel error messages, edit `config.txt` in the first partition.  Find the `kernel=` and change what's there to:

```
kernel=kernel7.img
```

If it doesn't exist, create it (but if it didn't exist I think it should have worked properly in the first place).

The kernel is currently the only difference for Raspbian; armv7 is backward compatible with armv6, so the userland works.  This other pi distros should work the same way -- you just need an armv7 kernel.   If there isn't one, you should be able to use the `kernel7.img` from Raspbian.  Make sure you also install the modules, which means copying `/lib/modules/3.X.X-v7` over (X.X is probably 18.5, the -v7 is what's important).

If you do want to use that route -- copying in a kernel and modules because you cannot or do not want to upgrade the OS -- [see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538) about how to mount an SD card *image* to get the files out.  Remember, the kernel will be in the first partition, the modules in the second.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

In the element14 webpage (http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-73878/l/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-frequently-asked-questions-faqs), you can find:

**Will the microSD card and Operating System from my previous model of Raspberry Pi work with the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?**
If you are using Raspbian, you will have to update it first. On your existing Raspberry Pi you can run the following commands from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Alternatively, you can download the latest SD Card image from raspberrypi.org/downloads

Comment: Note that if you've actually updated in the past 6+ months, you don't have to do this.  Also, if you are already using a jessie image (check `/etc/issue` -- jessie is v. 8) *don't* do a `dist-upgrade`.  In fact, you should not have to do a `dist-upgrade` from wheezy either, if you do not want to.  That should have a Pi 2 kernel (and modules), which is the only difference.