# Can I view/copy the contents of an img file from Windows?

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, windows

I have a backup .img file of an old Raspbian installation that I used to have running as a webserver. I'm unable to get the Raspberry Pi to boot from it any more, I think due to running out of space on the card but I could be wrong on that.

This backup has an old Wordpress website on it which I'd like to recover. So I'm wondering is there any way to access the contents, either from Windows? There is a [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image) which covers this on a Linux system, but is it possible from Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [Ext for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) and then **mount `img` file** and you will see the contents of mounted image.

Answer (score 9):

It also turns out that 7zip can extract a `.img` file just like any other archive file:

```
7z x raspian.img
```

Comment: There I am getting the img file from a zip file using 7-Zip.  All I need to do was double click it two more times.  First revealed another img file along with a 0.fat file.  Click on the second, inner, img and boom.  Thanks!  OK, copying those OS files on a windows machine and I get strange 7-Zip errors that I'll look into another day.  For now, I just want to see a few things in the pile-o-file.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, use DiskInternals' [Freeware Linux Reader for Windows](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) (as I was unable to figure out how to mount `.img` files with Paragon's *ExtFS for Windows*).

Comment: This tool works like a charm, and is really easy to use - helped me extract the configuration from Raspbian .img file.+1

Answer (score 1):

If you have your backup SD card, or can burn your image to any SD card, you can also use open source tool [ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) to access it.