# How can I mount or otherwise read the raspbian image on Windows?

Tags: raspbian, image, mount, windows

Same as [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image), but for Windows.

I have already unsuccessfully tried to open the [raspbian debian wheezy image](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest) with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) and [Ext2explore](http://ext2read.blogspot.ch/).

Next I'm going to install an Ubuntu Linux on VirtualBox and see if I can mount the raspbian image there. But I would prefer a more lightweight solution, if at all possible.

Comment: May I ask why would you need to read image? I'd imagine one can mount it   from Linux via loop device (assuming you have support for that filesystem).

Comment: Of course: I'm currently trying to run raspbian with qemu, which requires the modification of a few files inside the image. This can be done from within the running emulation, but I would prefer doing these things with Windows tools. It would also be nice if I could automate these steps eventually.

Comment: How to: Install and Run QEMU (Raspbian Emulator) on Windows - YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj1QCSJjysM

Comment: Yes thank you, but I am already able to run the emulation. That was just the background.

Comment: You might try something like virtual clone drive, but automation in windows is a joke so your better off using linux in virtualbox, you can use a small bat file to start vbox headless and linux will do all the work then turn itself off from there.

Comment: @user1133275 I guess I'm a joker... Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out: Virtual Clone Drive did not complain when I told it to mount the image, but Windows displayed an error when I tried to click on the mounted drive in windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The question you're linking now has a [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image#comment36187_13137) to a duplicate question to yours which features [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28464/51976), i.e. use the free trial of [Paragon ExtFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/). Alternatively, this [Freeware Linux Reader for Windows](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) worked for me.