# How to emulate a Raspbian image on a PC to access the data?

Tags: raspbian, image

Here is my problem:
I've created a stand-alone process for the raspberry pi. It runs a python script in the background using crontab, AND I've always the capability to continue working within Raspbian.

After used for a period of time (stand-aloned), when I try to plug it to a monitor to extract those files, the Raspberrypi doesn't get me to the Desktop. Just get stuck with a black image with a blinking underscore on the top left side of the screen.

I've tried other images, so there is no problem with the Raspberry Pi.

I don't know if there is any other solution to get inside, like emulating the same image (I've tried QEMU, but no luck).

Thanks for all,
It should be great if I could recover the data from the microSD.

Comment: On Windows (doesn't have ext Support by default) or on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I've found the solution from this thread:

[Can I view/copy the contents of an img file from Windows?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28457/can-i-view-copy-the-contents-of-an-img-file-from-windows)

I've used this software: http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

And I could get into the Raspbian folder structure to recover files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to access your data from an SD card image, there is no need to emulate the raspberry Pi. 
You can simply mount the image <strike>(e.g. if you are using windows, rename the file extension to .img and windows should offer you to mount it on right click)</strike>

Edit: I realized this only works for ISO files.

[Apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) (I am not using Windows) Ext2Read is able to read ext4 file systems in disk images.

My solution would be to  start Ubuntu in a virtual machine or from a live usb and mount the image there.

Comment: I just want to access the data within the folder (for example: /home/pi/folder_project

Comment: Then this should work for you. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Findus23 , so, I'll try that solution. I wish those folders are visible or at least able to copy data from there once mounted the .img  I'll keep you posted.