# First Boot expand filesystem does not take effect

Tags: boot, cmdline.txt

I have a raspbian lite SD Card Image.

I have expanded the `cmdline.txt` file by the following line `init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh`.

#### cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh
```

On the first boot, I get the blue screen (see picture below) for 1-2 seconds.

*"Resized Root filesystem. Restart in 5 seconds."* (<- this is the right text; picture is only an example!)

[image]

But the filesystem is not expanded!

If I call the script (`/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh`) by myself after boot, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your answer as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### by posting this thread, I got the answer for my own question. So now here is my solution!

I saw that the `/etc/init.d/resizefs_once` script and `/etc/rc3.d/S01resize2fs_once` is missing, which is build by `raspi-config` (source: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56623/57858).

After baking the image, I have mounted the image again and add the `/etc/init.d/resizefs_once` file

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          resize2fs_once
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Resize the root filesystem to fill partition
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting resize2fs_once" &&
    resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2 &&
    update-rc.d resize2fs_once remove &&
    rm /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once &&
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

and the missing symbolic link: `/etc/rc3.d/S01resize2fs_once`

`sudo ln -s /$PathToMountPoint$/etc/init.d/resize2fs_once /$PathToMountPoint$/etc/rc3.d/S01resize2fs_once`

Now everything works!

Hope this manual helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Dominic answer I could make it work.

I had to change a couple things to make it work in Raspbian 9 though.

This is my final code

```
# restore expand filesystem on first boot
  cat > /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          resize2fs_once
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Resize the root filesystem to fill partition
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting resize2fs_once" && \
    resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2 && \
    update-rc.d resize2fs_once remove && \
    rm /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once && \
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
EOF
  chmod +x /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once
  systemctl enable resize2fs_once
```