# How to make 3.5" Resistive Touch Screen Usable

Tags: setup, touchscreen

I just got [this touchscreen](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5-TFT-Touch-Screen-LCD-Display-for-Raspberry-Pi-B-W-Heatsinks-Case-SD-Card-/131454478595?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e9b4c2903) that you attach to the gpio. It comes with a special image for the Rpi 2 under a red link called "Materials for the latest raspberry pi 2". In that zip is an *.img file. Now my question is how do I set this screen up assuming I can ssh into the pi or use an hdmi screen.  Does this replace the operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently bought a 4 inch version of these screens and the image is supposed to replace the operating system with one that has a kernel supporting the use of the screen and being already set up.

You could try to get it working without using the image but my research revealed this to be a complicated and time consuming process that wasn't worth doing so I used the provided image instead.

You can update/upgrade after you have booted up to make sure its fully up to date but be careful if you try to update the bootloader as this can stop the touch function from working.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Thank you for your input! I assume the image is a *raspbian*?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an `.img` and it is for the pi, it's likely intended to be a whole card.  Have a look with it using `file` -- here's a recent Raspbian image:

```
> file 2015-01-31-raspbian.img 
2015-01-31-raspbian.img: ; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x0,130,3), end-CHS (0x7,165,30), startsector 8192, 114688 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x7,165,31), end-CHS (0x18e,97,19), startsector 122880, 6277120 sectors
```

You can tell this is a device image since it has two partitions in it.  Another test would be to use `fdisk` on it.  If so, you can mount the partitions and look in them if you want; [see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538) about that and `fdisk` usage.