# How to set up an LCD touch screen? I have a tinylcd35 touch screen

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I have tried the procedure in "www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/" but, I couldn't get it done. It's just showng a background white light but no booting can be seen in it. Can any one help me to fix it? I am using a tinylcd3.5 inch Touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread here: [How to make 3.5" Resistive Touch Screen Usable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31279/how-to-make-3-5-resistive-touch-screen-usable/31285#31285). You need to use a specific linux image usually provided with the screen which has the relevant drivers and settings already configured.

The reason you are getting a white screen is because linux is still configured to use HDMI and so no ouput is going to the touchscreen.

Comment: I didnt get any drivers or Os for this touch screen and this is the link of the product  "http://www.tinylcd.com/tiny149/product.php?id_product=33"

Comment: @SharathVedala at the bottom of that page there are links to linux images that you would need already on SD card in order for the screen to work. I would suggest emailing them to ask if there is a download link instead or if they can email you the image in a zip or something so you can copy it yourself.