# Ubuntu MATE image wont run

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu MATE pi image wont run.  I want it to run on a pi 2, but the green light just stays lit.  I also tried the imaged sd card on a pi B+ (just to test) and the green blinks 7 times.

I imaged the sd cards from the one available on raspberrypi.org with dd.  This is far from my first time using `dd` so I doubt that's the problem and both pis run rapsbian fine so there's no hardware problem.

Any way to get this to work?

Comment: How big is your SD Card? What class? How long did you let the RasPi idle for?

Comment: The pis idled for up to 10 minutes, but regardless the green light should have started flashing to indicate activity.  My SD card is 32gb.  It is now running raspbian fine, but I would still like to use ubuntu mate.

Comment: Okay, so the SD card itself is fine. Got it.

Comment: Do you get a Rainbow GPU screen?

Comment: Ubuntu MATE won't work on a B+ because Ubuntu is ARMv7 only.  This is why you get the "kernel not found" pattern of blinks.  Green light on steady w/ a Pi 2 is what happens if you have no SD card, the card is not inserted properly, or the SD card reader does not like/recognize the card (which can happen -- try a different brand/model).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can happen is that once you download the iso, it gets corrupted on download. You then try again and again to install on the SD, but it won't work because of the faulty download.

Can you try downloading it again and installing it for me?

According to [this](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern), LED blinking 7 times mean kernel.img is missing/corrupted. Make sure that this file isn't corrupt and **exists**.

Comment: Rather than downloading it again, you can mount and check the image file locally: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538 ...Including using `fsck` on the partitions.

Comment: Right. I keep thinking fsck is only for checking HDDs.