# SD card not accessible since writing image with dd

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu

I've first installed Raspbian via NOOBS (just placed the files on the SD Card using windows), which worked fine and Raspbian was start- and usable. Afterwards I wanted to set an static IP by changing cmdline.txt in boot (like described here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=24993 ). Because I've had some issues changing the SD cards content (first I've set the umask wrong when mounting, and after a successfull change I could not mount the boot-partition at all.

To overcome this issues, I've decided to install Raspbian manually by using the image from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ . The sha1-Hash of the download is correct. I've installed the Raspbian via:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Unfortunately is it not possible to boot the Pi from the SD card (the sceen stays black, the red and green light are constantly on) Furthermore, I can not access the file system of the SD card using Ubuntu. The following partitions seem to be available on the SD card:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 0 Dez  4 13:59 /dev/mmcblk0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 1 Dez  4 13:58 /dev/mmcblk0p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 2 Dez  4 13:58 /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

gparted says that the file system of both partitions is unknown.

The Raspberry is ok, as it is possible to boot it with a different SD card.

Is there something I've done wrong or something I could try? May the SD card be broken, or is there some problem in the installation process?

EDIT: fdisk -l 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img seems to be right:

```
Platte 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img: 3934 MByte, 3934257152 Byte
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 478 Zylinder, zusammen 7684096 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0xea0e7380

                         Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img1            8192      131071       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img2          131072     7684095     3776512   83  Linux
```

EDIT 2:

fdisk -l on the SD-card unfortunately does not return the same (and neither on the other partitions):

```
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~/workspaces/irpsimworkspace/backend/backend-utils$ fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Konnte /dev/mmcblk0 nicht öffnen
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~/workspaces/irpsimworkspace/backend/backend-utils$ fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0p1
Konnte /dev/mmcblk0p1 nicht öffnen
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~/workspaces/irpsimworkspace/backend/backend-utils$ fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0p2
Konnte /dev/mmcblk0p2 nicht öffnen
```

(I assume the output in english would be "Could not open /dev/mmcblk0")

EDIT 3:

But the SD card does not seem to be broken. Detecting badblocks does not find anything:

```
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~/workspaces/irpsimworkspace/backend/backend-utils$ sudo badblocks -o ./badblocks.list -w -s -v -b 4096 -c 16 /dev/mmcblk0
Suche nach defekten Blöcken (Lesen+Schreiben-Modus)
Von Block 0 bis 7593983
Teste mit Muster 0xaa:  84.43% erledigt, 33:26 verstrichen. (0/0/0 Fehler)
```

EDIT 4:

I have an SD card reader on an Thinkpad T440s with Ubuntu 14.04. The card is realy accessible via /dev/mmcblk0.

After badblocks ran for a longer time, it displayed errors. I've now changed the SD-card and the Pi seems to work fine now. So all in all my lesson learned is to have much more patience for badblocks to finish.

Comment: Have you [tried this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538)?  What does the output of `fdisk -l 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img` say?

Comment: How about `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`?  They should be the same.

Comment: On what machine di you run `dd`. `/dev/mmcblk0` is how the SD is on the Pi itself. You can't install on the Pi (unless you have SD reader, in which case it wouldn't be `/dev/mmcblk0`