# how do i add a .img file to my sd card that has the OS?

Tags: software-installation

I jusr got a 3.5" lcd touch screen. I have an .img file from the manufacturer. How can I add this onto an existing SD? Can I just install it through a command line?

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is possible that this .img file is a full system with a patched kernel fixed up to work with this particular touch screen. In this case it is difficult or impossible to extract what's necessary to integrate it into an existing OS. For helpful answers however you need to provide more information, including make and model of said LCD, maybe a link to that .img file, information about your current OS on your SD card. You can always add your question to add those information.

Comment: Who or what is an mfr?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Manufacturer.

Answer (score 4):

No. An `.img` is usually an entire filesystem or device image; in the case of the pi the latter, usually containing two partitions.

It is meant to be written directly onto the card and will destroy whatever is currently on it.

Comment: well. you could mount the partitions from the image and copy the desired files (if known)...

Comment: Yes.  [See here for instructions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538).  In the case of a screen, it is probably just about kernel drivers, so in fact doing this would be relatively easy.