# Kernel panics on Raspberry Pi 3 after update/upgrade cycle

Tags: pi-3

I bought 2x Raspberry Pi 3s and 3x Kingston SD cards.

I downloaded the latest version of Raspbian, and did an update/upgrade cycle. After rebooting, I get a kernel panic:

[image]

Everything works great and as expected until I do a reboot.

After researching, I found out that I had an under powered adapter and have switched that, but, I am now getting the exact same problem of both Pis using any card.

Does anyone have any advice here?

Comment: No normal human being can read the screenshot. Post text.

Comment: @Milliways Click on it!

Comment: @WilliamHilsum can you try a reboot after unplugging all of your devices from your RPi

Comment: @ahmetertem I only had a keyboard plugged in, but it happens even without that.

Comment: I'd think with a substantial S.U. account you would understand that you do not ask a question, then decide 6 hours later after receiving feedback that the question you meant to ask is a completely different one, so you change your question.  *Please do not re-edit this question that way again.*   **If you have a new question, ask a new question.**

Comment: @goldilocks - It is the exact same outcome I need answered about what caused it/how to fix it... I just have a lot more detail and now know the possible cause, but ideally want feedback from someone knowledgable.

Comment: That's great, then ask a new question and refer to this one if you wish.  I am sure I do not have to explain SE to you -- we are *not* a discussion forum, etc.   This question has to do with diagnosing  a kernel panic.  The question you changed it into was about whether or not SD cards could be damaged by an insufficient power supply.  If you do ask a new question, make sure to mention the exact model of card, not just the brand.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to read if you zoom in.  Unfortunately it's hard to tell the when the problem starts because it already has.  Although it is unlikely to make much difference for you in the end, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501712/stop-tty-from-scrolling-down) about using <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd> to pause/resume output and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll through it.  Note that it is too late if you wait for the crash -- after that it will be frozen.

I'd just try reinstalling everything in the first partition [from a new image](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538).  Just make sure when you do this that you check that whatever directory in in `/lib/modules` on the *2nd partition* (the root filesystem, presuming Raspbian) is also in yours.  The directory will be named after a kernel verison, like `4.1.19-v7+`.  You may have multiple directories there, but the fresh image will only have one.  If you already have a directory with *exactly* that version number, you don't have to replace it.  To sum up:

- Replace everything in the boot partition with stuff from a new image (or the image file you used originally, if you still have it).
- Make sure you have the kernel's module directory, inside `/lib/modules` on the root fs, in the same place on your SD card.

Comment: I think I unfortunately found the error with the SD card, although I am still a little confused as to why, so, I have updated the question. Thank you so much for this though.