# How to login as root remotely?

Tags: ssh, remote, login, root

I am trying to login to the raspberrypi as root user via winscp, but it only says "Access denied", same thing for trying to login directly as root on ssh.

I have tried loging in as pi and doing `sudo passwd root`, which results in the console output `passwd: Password changed successfully`, however I still can't login as root

Comment: It is possible. But is it wise to allow remote root login? Most people are better off leaving remote root login disabled and using sudo, when required. A sensibly secure default has been chosen for a reason.

Comment: Is a there a counterpart to sudo when you want to ftp? if not I have a valid reason to login as root from filezilla and use my favorite editor on my PC to edit any file on the bloody raspberry pi. I don't want to use the crap nano, emacs, vi, ...etc :) it's backwards.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to login as root using SSH or WinSCP you need to edit the config of SSHD, do this:

- Login, and edit this file: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Find this line: `PermitRootLogin without-password`
- Edit: `PermitRootLogin yes`
- Close and save file
- `reboot` or restart sshd service using: `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`
- Set a root password if there isn't one already: `sudo passwd root`

Now you can login as `root`, but I recommend you using strong password or ssh-keys

Comment: Note that if the `PermitRootLogin` line starts with a comment sign (`#`) you have to remove that sign!

Comment: I was helped the last line to set root password. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally check the ownership of the authorized_keys file. My /root/.ssh/authorized_keys was owned by the wrong user and I kept getting my key rejected on login.

Comment: I have tried this but still unable to transfer a file with Putty or WinSCP to a /home/pi/docker/homeAssistant/backups folder

Answer (score 7):

You cannot login as `root` because `Raspbian` does not have a `root` password. See [Raspbian root default password](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47126/raspbian-root-default-password/47127#47127)

Normally `ssh` does not allow `root` access because this is considered a security risk. You should be able to do everything you need using `sudo` (which is the normal Debian practice).

If you REALLY want `ssh` `root` access it can be enabled.

Comment: I'm very glad someone at least pointed out that this is a security risk. SSH as root is never a good idea (particularly when using password auth).

Comment: so how can I transfer a backup file to a /Home folder if I cannot have permission to my own files!

Answer (score 3):

You can login as normal user (belong ***sudoer*** group) then

```
 sudo su -
```

to switch to ***root***

Comment: For ssh that's fine, the main problem was winscp where I can't just use sudo

Answer (score -1):

You can

```
sudo su
```

Then use **passwd** to change the password