# How can I recover from a system boot autoload service that keeps rebooting?

Tags: raspbian, boot, systemd

I don't want to start over from scratch.
There are several ways I could change the monitor.service so it would fail or run without booting:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl --full edit monitor.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/monitor.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl stop monitor.service
```

edit the app monitor.py so it won't have the option to reboot.
change a value in the file cmdfile.txt so it won't take the reboot path in the app.

But it already reboots before any of the above options are available.

I Have a limited number of options:
Since I don't want to reload the system NOOBS.
1) hold down Shift when the raspberry pi screen comes up.
2) select Edit config
3) click cmdline.txt
4) add " init/bin/bash" to the end of the command line.
5) click OK
6) click Exit
7) it will reboot and stop at the bash.sh prompt # (I have to push enter to get the prompt)

At this time I can
change directories: `cd`
list files: `ls`
read files: `sudo nano monitor.py`
I can not modify them: [ file 'monitor.py' is unwriteable ]
I can not change their permissions: `chmod 666 monitor.py`
chmod changing permissions of 'monitor.py' Read only file system
I suspect these are images only before being loaded into the system.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained
Is there anything in config.txt that I could un-comment or add?

I need a different option than "`init/bin/bash`" in the command line that runs later in the boot process and allows me to modify files.
Or I need to know how to enable bash.sh to modify files. -- I suspect the files are not loaded yet.
I would like to use " `systemctl stop monitor.service`"
I would like to stop boot right before monitor.service runs.
exit takes me to a dead end and I can turn the power off.

I suspect I could change the files if I loaded them on Linux file system for Windows.
https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/#
I see where I could change it to read/write: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2`
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/how-do-i-start-up-in-safemode
but I am not ready to take that leap and my partitions are different (or I don't understand them) `/dev/mmcblk0p7`
I keep looking for a magic command that asks me
"Hey Bozo, do you want to run your bad, screwed up monitor.service?"
And I'll chose No.
Or a set of keystrokes that stops autoload right after the raspberry pi screen opens and before idle.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repair most such problems on the Pi by rebooting to a root shell.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files.

**NOTE** if you are running NOOBS the appropriate `cmdline.txt` WILL NOT be in the first partition, but one of the other FAT partitions (depends on what you installed).