# RaspberryPi keeps rebooting after i changed rc.local file

Tags: raspbian, boot, reboot

my raspberryPi keeps rebooting and I have no idea how to solve this problem other than recovery the image. I haven't backuped for a while so I prefer not to recover it from an old one.

**Background**

I added two lines of code in rc.local file hoping to run two python scripts at boot. These two python scripts run in indefinite loops. One of them has a condition. if met, then it will run `os.system('reboot now')`

**Problem**

After I added the lines and started the system to test it out. Both programs were booted successfully and after the condition was met, the system started to reboot. But it just got stuck in the reboot process and I switched the SD card to another Pi and it is doing the same thing.

**Question**

Is there a way to enter recovery mode maybe? Or any other ways to stop it from rebooting?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

**EDITED**

Here is python script that reboots the PI once the condition is met

```py
beginTime = time.time()
try:
    while True:
        paths = glob("/home/pi/odas/recordings/cSST*.raw")
        # paths might be empty at the very beginning
        if not paths:
            print("cSST files have been not created yet")
            flagTime = beginTime
        else:     
            latestFilePath = max(paths, key=os.path.getatime)
            latestFileTime = os.path.getatime(latestFilePath)
            flagTime = latestFileTime

        currentTime = time.time()
        delta = currentTime - flagTime
        print(delta)

        if delta > 120:
            os.system("reboot now")

        time.sleep(2)   
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("User interrupt")
```

So this script is monitoring files in a folder. If 2 minutes have passed and there are no new files being generated then reboot the system

Comment: Show me your python programs.

Comment: If you have no Linux PC to edit the file with, your best bet is to [start up in safemode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/how-do-i-start-up-in-safemode)

Comment: @tlfong01 I pasted the script. sorry for the late reply

Comment: #Yihan Hu, No problem. I read your program and found it good, and @goldilocks indeed gave a very good answer with helpful troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repair most such problems on the Pi by rebooting to a root shell.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.  (This needs to be performed by mounting the SD Card on another computer.)
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files.

**NOTE** if you are running NOOBS the appropriate `cmdline.txt` WILL NOT be in the first partition, but one of the other FAT partitions (depends on what you installed).

Comment: how do I do step 1 if whenever I plug PI to power, it just reboots?

Comment: Ah I found some other useful sources that teach you how to do that, I will try it!

Comment: I tried this method and I kept getting `can't find PARTUUID=61f5b861-02`, any thoughts?

Comment: I somehow solved it in this question that I just posted: <https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/reboot-to-a-boot-shell-to-remount-as-read-write-error>

Answer (score 1):

> this script is monitoring files in a folder. If 2 minutes have passed and there are no new files being generated then reboot the system

To debug this you would need to print `flagTime` and `currentTime` to a log when they are initialized.  If you had done this, I think you would notice that `delta` is indeed > 120 seconds even though much less time elapsed between the `time.time()` calls.

The Pi does not have a built-in real time clock, and depends on a system daemon getting the correct time off the network (after which it can keep time easily).  This does not happen instantaneously, and may not happen at all; before that point it uses a somewhat arbitrary value from a previous shutdown, but you should not count on this being anything in particular.

When it does get the real time, it sets the time, which is almost certainly a jump forward *that occurs during the boot process*, or perhaps even afterward, depending on circumstance and how you want to conceptualize "boot process".  While `rc.local` is supposed to be run near or at the end, "run" refers to *starting* something, and although it may have started after the network time daemon, it may still be starting **before** that daemon gets the time, hence a jump in system time may occur while your script is running.

I'm not a python user, but the docs for `time.time()` indicate it returns seconds since the epoch, which is a calendar time value that will vary if the system clock ("calendar time") is changed.  If you want to measure the actual elapsed time avoiding this pitfall, you need to use your own timer, or a time function that uses a monotonic clock guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: Ok I will see what happens there. I have now successfully retrieved my system back.