# When I power my Raspberry Pi 4, it shows only following window and remains still. What should I do now? Plz help

Tags: pi-4, login

[![When I power my Raspberry Pi 4, it shows only following window and remains still. What should I do now? Plz help
It took me hours to solve this problem but same situation till now.
How to fix this? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hidmq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hidmq.jpg)

Comment: [you can you boot in safe mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/how-do-i-start-up-in-safemode) then undo whatever it is you've done to break it

Comment: Please explain what you have done to break it.

Comment: I've tried alot by pressing alt+ctrl+F keys then login info is shown, I've entered login info and password many times but no responce comes out neither it accepts login info nor it shows any other response still same black & white wi dow display is shown again and again.. I'm not able to do this still now..

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image. So that users can replicate the issue.