# Can't boot after external usb disk died

Tags: hard-drive

I've got a pi 3b that boots from the ssd card, but has an external usb drive to store media files. The external drive seems to have died (makes terrible sounds and doesn't spin up) but the bigger problem is that I can't access the system anymore. While booting it times out after waiting for the bad device, then reports "You are in emergency mode." After a few more messages it says

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page fore more details. 

Press Enter to continue.
```

But pressing enter or switching to other virtual consoles doesn't give me a command or login prompt. I tried [booting in safemode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/how-do-i-start-up-in-safemode) by adding `S` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` but there's no change.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of your `/boot/cmdline.txt` to it.

Comment: What is "ssd card", a solid-state drive, or a secure digital card?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this method and the command line is not correct for current Raspbian. You should list **your actual `cmdline.txt`**

Your best option is to restore from your backup.

If you do not have a backup you can attempt to repair problems on the Pi by rebooting to a root shell. This won't work if you have used [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot. (This will need to be done on another computer.)
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files.

Comment: No dice. Adding `init=/bin/sh` makes the boot hang early after `random: crng init done` but with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

So, this worked for me. From this article all i did was:

1. add the `init=/bin/sh` to the cmdline.txt file in the /boot partition of the SD card for the pi.
2. once you are in the cmd prompt enter `sync` twice

`kali@kali:~ sync`

`kali@kali:~ sync`

3. run `exit`

`kali@kali:~ exit`

When you run the `exit` command you will get a load of kernel warnings. Ignore these and wait for them to finish then off the pi. Remove the line from step 1. Reboot the pi and all should be fine.

Let me know if this works for you

Reference: https://talhasariyuerek.com/en/linux-raspberry-pi-3b3b4-emergency-mode-root-account-locked-solution/

Comment: Just running `sync` will not fix anything. Sounds like have skipped a couple of crucial steps from the tutorial.