# SOLVED Edit rc.local from windows

Tags: boot, win32diskimager

I ruined my RPi, by using Python script in rc.local which shutdowns RPi as soon as it starts. Thus I cannot even login or ssh. How could I edit SD card from windows to change that rc.local file?

Comment: boot into safe mode, use [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/70527/135303) (not the accepted answer) - note, you will need keyboard and screen on the pi

Comment: thanks, but I already installed fresh OS to sd card. I retrieved all important data with win32imager and 7zip

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done on Windows, but it can be fixed on any Linux system (which can be a Pi).

You can repair most such problems on the Pi itself by rebooting to a root shell.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then edit files to fix the problem.

4. Remove `init=/bin/sh` from `cmdline.txt` and reboot.