# What is the Nextcloudpi default UNIX command line credentials?

Tags: nextcloud

A [Nextcloudpi](https://ownyourbits.com/nextcloudpi/) image was burned to an SD card.  A keyboard and monitor are attached: what is the default username and password for BASH (command line) access?

Comment: try `pi`  `raspberry`

Comment: @jsotola Good suggestion: no joy.  I believe I changed the default password, so I am seeking a reference that states the default username\pw.

Comment: couple more found on  Nextcloudpi website ...  https://docs.nextcloudpi.com/en/how-to-configure-nextcloudpi/ ... this one is confusing ... could be `root` `1234` or `Armbian` `1234` or `root` `Armbian`

Comment: post a question on Nextcloudpi forum

Comment: The default `username / password` is `pi / raspberry` as [this link](https://docs.nextcloudpi.com/en/how-to-configure-nextcloudpi/). - *I changed the default password.* You changed the default password and you want us to tell you the changed password?! - What do you mean by "I am seeking a reference that states the default username\pw."?

Comment: You can do this without the system running (remove any password): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47129/5538 The method is described for `root` but you can do the same thing for `pi` or whoever. Then when you login, just hit return when asked for a password.  You can then use `passwd` to set it to whatever you want.

Comment: @M.Rostami  Thank you: your link is exactly what I am seeking.   To clarify,  because attempts to login with pi/raspberry fails, the pw must have been changed: I do not expect anyone to divine the pw, however, I wanted to ensure that I am using a valid default username (`pi`).   The goal is to restore UNIX command line access.  Suggestions / solutions are appreciated.

Comment: @gatorback I'm glad. "*The goal is to restore UNIX command-line access. Suggestions / solutions are appreciated.*", it would better if you ask another question for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `username / password` is `pi / raspberry` as [this link](https://docs.nextcloudpi.com/en/how-to-configure-nextcloudpi/). On a QWERTZ keyboard type `z` instead of `y` because QWERTY keyboard layout is set by default.  If you can not login as `pi` user, change the password.

To clarify, because attempts to login with `pi` fails, the password must have been changed.

You can login without the system running (remove any password) by [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47129/5538). (Thanks to @[gatorback](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/40373/gatorback)) Note that the method is described for `root`, however, you can do it for `pi` or any other users.