# sudo: command not found

Tags: sudo

My USB stick is now full of backups, and I need to delete at least one to upgrade Nextcloud.
I cant.

I try `rm -f ./nextcloud-bkp_2017*`
and I get:

```
rm: cannot remove './nextcloud-bkp_20171211.tar': Permission denied
```

So I try `sudo rm -f ./nextcloud-bkp_2017*`
and get:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I then try `su`
And, it asks for a password.

I have tried every password I know, and some I didn't.

It always comes up:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

I even try (without knowing if it's the correct app):

```
apt install sudoer
```

and, of course, get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Is there anything I can do?

Where did sudo go?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47129/5538

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Please add the output of `which sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

If sudo is not installed and you don't know the root password, the only way would be to attach your USB stick to another PC and clean it up.

If sudo is installed, then it may be a path setting problem. The "sudo" binary should normally be in "/usr/bin". You can search for it:

```
find / -name sudo 2>/dev/null
```

(the "2>/dev/null" part is to get rid of all "Permission denied" warnings you get in the result)

And then use the path:

```
/usr/bin/sudo rm -f ./nextcloud-bkp_2017*
```

If it works, you need to see what is wrong in "/etc/profile" file (where the PATH is originally set) and fix it.

It would help if you mention you RasPi and OS versions. And also what user you are logged on with.

Comment: Well, certainly I got somewhere:
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Structure needs cleaning
It still didn't clear the files.
All I know is:
NextCloudPi v0.46.6, and it's a PiB
There's no lsb or lshw.

Comment: @user256787 so you can sudo now. That "Structure needs cleaning" means the file system is corrupted. Normally you should unmount the disk and use "e2fsk" to fix it. Google the error or ask in a seperate question in linux forums.