# How can I find these files?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, image, bare-metal

I am roughly following [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones#Booting_the_Kernel) tutorial and have created a kernel.img.

It says:

> Do you still have the SD card with the original Raspbian image on it from when you where testing the hardware above? Great. So you already have a SD card with a boot partition and the required files. If not then download one of the original raspberry boot images and copy them to the SD card.

I do not have the files on my SD card so my question is, where do I find all of the other files in the "original raspberry boot image"?

Comment: have you downloaded Raspbian (not noobs) and flashed it to your SD card? Also you say "you are roughly following" how do you sort of follow the instructions and expect the same end results? How do we know what parts you followed and what parts you didn't.

Comment: Ok, I followed it EXACTLY except that I plan on modifying the code as soon as I get this to work...

Comment: no, I do not have raspbian...

Comment: That would probably explain why you don't have the files on your card. So you skipped the testing phase of the tutorial - go back and download Raspbian and copy it to your card.

Comment: I already had it working but wanted to go bare metal so wiped it.

Comment: Then recreate it that is what yopu need. Again you are roughly following the tutorial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46797/discussion-between-dalearn-and-steve-robillard).

Answer (score 2):

> Do you still have the SD card with the original Raspbian image? ...Great. So you already have a SD card with a boot partition and the required files. If not then download one of the original raspberry boot images and copy them to the SD card.

This seems pretty straightforward.  [Those can be found here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)  You might as well use the `lite` image, since you only need the contents of the first small partition.

The files themselves can also be found in [this github repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot).

> I do not have the files on my SD card

Then you will need to either:

- Burn the image to the card properly following the installation guide linked from the download page above. Or:
- Mount the image directly [as described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538) and copy the files out. Or:
- Download the files from the github repo.

In the last two cases you will have to format the card yourself.