# Where can I find a copy of the original config settings, I want to compare what I have vs what was?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I have been trying a lot of different things out on my Pi.  Some of the Expansion cards asked me to put `#` in front of certain lines.

Comment: As it stands this question is too vague. Be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Be more specific about which config files you're referring to. If some documentation asks you to modify specific files and certain lines then it should point out which files and which lines. To backup config files before modifications is usually left to *you* while you of course could always find the original files in the distribution you used to install your system.

Answer (score 1):

As the sole user of your Pi and thus as acting system administrator the task of backing up config files before editing them is your responsibility. They're usually not automatically saved to another location. If you edit them you better make sure you have a working backup beforehand. That being said it is of course possible to obtain the files you're looking for:

1. If you have installed your Raspbian from a downloaded image (e.g. as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/)) and have that image still available you can mount the image and search the files you're interested in. This question: [How can I mount a Raspberry Pi Linux distro image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/19949) outlines what needs to be done to mount the image. Note that config files may be updated by the package manager. So if you have an old image and an updated system there is the remote but existant chance that the config files are different.
2. It should also be possible to retrieve any files from [Raspbian's online repository](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository).

Comment: When you've mounted that image, you could also use `diff` to compare it to your current one…