# Can't mount raspberry after I've burn raspbian

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, software-installation, filesystem, partition

**Given**:
So, I have an 8 GB sd card.

**TODO:** 
Get raspbian

**Solution**:

First I delete the partition:

```
Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.
```

After i've created a new partition:

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type
  p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
  e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1):  
First sector (2048-15130623, default 2048):  
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-15130623, default 15130623):  

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 7.2 GiB.
```

This is how it looks:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7746879488 bytes, 15130624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa208ea74

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 15130623 15128576  7.2G 83 Linux
```

Setting table:

```
Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1

Hex code (type L to list all codes): b
If you have created or modified any DOS 6.x partitions, please see the fdisk documentation for additional information.
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32'.
```

Saving Changes

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Making it bootable:

```
Command (m for help): a
Selected partition 1
The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now.
```

print:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7746879488 bytes, 15130624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa208ea74

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15130623 15128576  7.2G  b W95 FAT32
```

Saving changes

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Formating:

```
Wed Oct 18; 23:57:49; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
```

After that I just burned the image:

```
Wed Oct 18; 23:58:27; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  sudo dd bs=4M if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/
dev/sdb1 conv=fsync
442+1 records in
442+1 records out
1854590976 bytes (1.9 GB) copied, 461.441 s, 4.0 MB/s
```

After that the image was visible and mountable, but now when I plug it in :

```
Thu Oct 19; 09:50:11; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  mount /dev/sdb
mount: can't find /dev/sdb in /etc/fstab
Thu Oct 19; 09:51:30; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  mount /dev/sdb1
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab
```

**QUESTION: WHY IS IT NOT MOUNTABLE ?**

Helpful info:

```
Thu Oct 19; 10:04:53; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         1958676         0   1958676   0% /dev
tmpfs            1965996     26480   1939516   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1965996      2112   1963884   1% /run
tmpfs            1965996         0   1965996   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /.snapshots
/dev/sda4         166724      4624    162100   3% /boot/efi
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /usr/local
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/spool
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /tmp
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/opt
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/pgsql
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/crash
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/mariadb
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/named
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/mailman
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/lib/libvirt/images
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/tmp
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /var/log
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /srv
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /opt
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sda7       40009728  38632340    238892 100% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sda1      314428412 134355888 180072524  43% /backup
/dev/sda8       59510384  14210312  45300072  24% /home


Thu Oct 19; 10:05:29; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  mount | grep media
Thu Oct 19; 10:06:09; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are following this bizarre approach, rather than just [installing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) the image.

Comment: @Milliways I've used EXACTLY THE SAME guide with EXACTLY THE SAME COMMANDS to install the image.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve.  Either tell us what you are trying to achieve with this rather odd procedure or just burn the image direct to a SD card as intended.

Comment: @joan yes, sorry, something is going wrong. I want to mount my drive, but it can't.

Comment: @joan Thu Oct 19; 09:50:11; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  mount /dev/sdb
mount: can't find /dev/sdb in /etc/fstab
Thu Oct 19; 09:51:30; marton;/backup/desktop/programs/images ;  $  mount /dev/sdb1
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab

Comment: The Raspberry Pi image is a complete SD card image.  It makes no sense to copy it to a partition within an SD card (/dev/sdb1 rather than /dev/sdb) as it is not a file system.

Comment: ok what should I do ? just format it ?

Comment: I guess the `mount` command required mount path as well. From the error message it looks for the entry in fstab, where the ultimate info available to mount the any specific volume. can you add proper entry in fstab & try mounting it ?

Comment: Hartun, I must agree with Joan and Milliways. Why are you trying to do this instead of simply burning the completed `.img` file provided by the foundation?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Well, I am asking what did I do wrong, if you new the answer, instead of critisizing me, maybe, you could have just told me that I don't have to partition and format my device. I don't know that, probably that's why I am asking.

Comment: @Hartun: Knowing intent helps answer questions. Users on the SE network often fall victim to the XY problem, and without knowing intent, answers are often wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Raspbian image is not a *filesystem* image, it's a *device* image.  It is intended to be used like this:

```
dd bs=4M if=2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite.img \
   of=/dev/sdb conv=fsync
           ^^^
```

Note, not `sdb1` (a partition, into which you could usefully copy a *filesystem*), but a *block device node*.  Admittedly, a partition device node can also be considered a block device (because it is random access), but hopefully the point is clear.

When you write the Raspbian image to a device, it will overwrite everything, so **there is no point in preformatting the card**.  When it is done, there will be two partitions (and [an MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), so it is bootable), but those all come from the image.

Note that you *can* create the card by formatting it with partitions and then copying stuff in from the partitions in the image, but to do that you need to either [mount the image](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538), or else do some math based on `fdisk -l raspbian.img` and copy over the partitions (in which case you don't have to format them, just create the partition table).  However, there is not much point to that.