# How to export a Linux instance from VirtualBox to a plain text filesystem?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystem, virtualization

For example, Raspberry Pi images can be "burned" to an SD card from an image file that contains a simple plain-text file tree that is the Raspbian (a Debian sub-flavor) filesystem (e.g., as discussed [here](https://learnaddict.com/2017/09/16/locally-mounting-a-raspberry-pi-raspbian-linux-image/))

And using VirtualBox,it's very convenient to do operations, such as installs of large packages, that would be slow on a Raspberry Pi.

But how to easily export the resulting o/s instance as a Raspbian image (e.g., without problems cause by `proc` and so on)?

Comment: virtualbox can't run a arm based os as far as I'm aware *`VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product`* - so, besides the fact that I have no idea what the first sentence is even saying, I can tell you that virtualbox is not a solution to "do operations that would be slow on a Raspberry Pi"

Comment: Are you looking for a "Virtual machine => Physical machine" conversion?

Comment: @JaromandaX - I've clarified the question to be clear that I mean a o/s image.

Comment: @MatsK - I am looking to create a Raspbian `.img` file from a VirtualBox instance.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Separately: VirtualBox will run Raspbian, as I've got that running myself.

Comment: are you sure that you are using virtualbox?  https://www.virtualbox.org  .... are you sure that you are running raspbian and not debian?

Comment: Are you sure you are running Raspbian for the arm based Pi and not the desktop version for x86?

Comment: Yes, there is an x86 Raspbian - hardly useful for Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...from an image file that contains a simple plain-text file tree...

This is gobbledygook.  You are confused.  That is not what an operating system image file is.  It is a binary, block-for-block duplication of either a single filesystem, or (as with the ones used for the Raspberry Pi), a block device containing multiple partitions and a boot sector.

This is why all you have to do with the Raspbian image to create a usable SD card is copy it to the card with `dd`.

> e.g., as discussed here

What is discussed there is not anything to do with "a simple plain-text file tree".  If you want a better understanding of what that script is for, [here is an explanation of the exact same process](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13138/5538).

> using VirtualBox,it's very convenient to do operations, such as installs of large packages, that would be slow on a Raspberry Pi

VirtualBox is a hypervisor for x86(-64).<sup>1</sup>  It does not emulate foreign architectures such as [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) (the category the Pi falls into), therefore it is impossible to run an operating system in it that has been compiled for the Pi.

While Raspbian [is available for PC hardware](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/), you cannot use it to do what you want to do since these two versions are not binary compatible.

> how to easily export the resulting o/s instance

In fact you can create an image file of the sort described above ("a binary, block-for-block duplication of a filesystem") from a VirtualBox using [`VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi).

> as a Raspbian image

You could, but this would not be an image that could be run on an actual Raspberry Pi.

You might have a look into [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU), although note that the combination of hardware emulation and the less performance oriented ARM ISA will probably mean it is noticeably slower than VirtualBox.  However, I believe you can run unadulterated Raspbian in it.

---

<sup>1. X86(-64) is by far the most widespread *[instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)* (ISA) for contemporary PCs (desktops, laptops, inc.
 Apple machines).  ISA's are used in hardware implementation, meaning they are carved in metal for specific physical systems.  Software is compiled to *machine code* which corresponds with this.  Software compiled for one ISA is unlikely to be compatible with another.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps there's confusion because you can get Raspbian for x86 - https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX -- I was not aware of that and will try to work in an appropriate edit!

Comment: The solution in qemu-raspbian-network.git worked for me to get headless raspbian running fine on qemu on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [(how-to)](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/06/raspbian-on-qemu-with-network-access/) . 

This is using the rasbian_lite_latest image.  So far I have not been able to get the standard raspbian desktop to show.

I did ` sudo raspi-config` and followed the directions to install `lightdm`.  But now, the system never gets past the initial login screen.  

I am pretty sure that the plain raspbian_latest image will work well, however.

Comment: Even though the solution above requires a kernel cross-compiled to ARM Versatile, updates to the mounted image would seem to work on R Pi hardware because the solution just overrides the image's existing kernel.