# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu, pi-3b+

I would like to get Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+. According to [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=208538&start=100#p1301685) this should be possible. Here is the summary on how they achieved it:

> Copy the following files from Raspbian to Ubuntu Mate:
>
> - **For Booting:**
>     copy bootcode.bin, fixup.dat, start.elf, bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb and
>     kernel7.img
> - **For keyboard/mouse:** copy /lib/modules/4.9.80-v7+ (root
>     partition)
> - **For network:** copy the contents of /lib/firmware/brcm/ (root
>     partition)
>
> If you want to boot from USB:
>
> - edit cmdline.txt, change
>     root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 to root=/dev/sda2 (boot partition)
> - edit etc/fstab,
>     change/dev/mmcblk0p2 to sda2 and /dev/mmcblk0p1 to sda1 (root
>     partition)

My question is where to copy /lib/modules/*-v7+ and /lib/firmware/brcm from the root partition. I was able to get raspian running on the raspberry pi 3B+ and then I copied the /lib/* files/folders to a usb stick. But I don't know where to put them on the sd card with ubuntu mate on it. I would copy them to the same location if I had ubuntu mate running on the pi already. However, I don't get this far.

Other steps I did so far:

- mount raspian image
- mount ubuntu mate image
- copy files from the boot partition (bootcode.bin, fixup.dat, start.elf, bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb and kernel7.img) of the mounted raspian image to the mounted ubuntu mate image.

I was then able to boot from this sd card to the point where I got the following error and could not type any commands:

> Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
>
> See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details
>
> ...

But I don't know how to fix this error because I cannot enter any commands.
The only thing that works is switching terminals using Ctrl+Alt+F1...

Comment: I know that there already exists an [image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=208538&start=100#p1301685) that should work. However, I would like to know how to create such a image by mixing the two images (mate and raspian).

Comment: Copy them to the root fs `/lib` directory.  Linux distros are all identical WRT where kernel modules and firmware go.

Comment: The problem is that I dont get to the root fs because of the mentioned error. Should it be possible to boot the raspberry pi only with the files copied from the boot partition?

Comment: The sd cards I created using dd and the images do not contain a lib folder

Comment: I know the folder is on the root partition / but as far as I know I must first boot the os to even get to the root folder. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The root filesystem is in one of the partitions in the image.  It should be pretty easy to recognize because it will be big, at least a few GB, and it will contain a normative linux root fs (/bin, /usr, **/lib**, /home, etc.).  There may only be two partitions, one of which is the small vfat boot one and the other the ext4 root fs; since you've booted it already this is presumably correct.  If there is only one partition, you did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So far I always mounted the downloaded img files on macOS which only shows me the boot partition. I guess it should be possible to mount the root partition using `mount` with the offset option. Or is there another way to access the root fs?

Comment: I dont know exactly whats the best way  to mount a partition within a *.img file.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/13137/5538

Comment: After a Hard Googling, I found out that there is an image for the Rpi 3 B+
I found a video tutorial on YouTube Have a look : [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7xcd3I72Gw)

Comment: I have a working version for the 3 B+. Here's my Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dugl2vndrg7zi37/PINN_v2_5_4_UbuntuMATE_16_04_2_RPi3_B_Plus.zip?dl=0

Comment: I wrote the latest MATE and Raspbian images to separate SD cards. Then I moved the files which the OP listed into exactly the same matching paths on the MATE SD file system. The latest Raspbian had a newer version of the keyboard/mouse drivers, which I copied over as if I had the version specified above. I've had no trouble with apt updates and software installs, as long as I get source code instead of binaries. I'm really happy with how it is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you are starting; the Ubuntu MATE image is very old - 16.04.2 and there have been updates to 16.04.4, but you need a working image to perform the update.

Ubuntu MATE has not had a firmware/kernel update for some time (since Wimpy left?) and AFAIK none are planned; 18.04 should be available in July.

The Pi3B+ NEEDS new firmware/kernel to boot, but this is only a first step; ideally the OS needs to be tested for compatibility. (Ubuntu MATE is still using a 4.4 kernel, and 4.9 had significant changes - Raspbian in now using 4.14.)

You could try `rpi-update` (although this needs to be used with caution), OR copy `raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` from a Raspbian site (I have not tried this), OR copy the new bootloader and kernels PLUS their modules from a Raspbian installation.

Updating is really a job for an expert Linux user.