# Ubuntu Server 18.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+: Ethernet Networking Errors on Boot

Tags: raspbian-stretch, web-server, ubuntu, pi-3b+, raspbian-lite

So I've been trying to setup a web server on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+

I'd like to be able to develop on meteor and then upload the app to my Pi over SSH and Meteor Up (MUP). Started with Raspbian Stretch Lite but couldn't get MUP to deploy the basic meteor app to it. Then decided to try Ubuntu server 16.04/18.04 as I have successfully done the above on an Ubuntu non-pi server.

I tried this img (non-net boot): https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

and this img (classic server 16.04): https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/

without success on the B+

Now I was checking out this wiki page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

and it says "The official Raspberry Pi 2 images can be used with a Pi 3 B/B+ after minor changes" found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Booting_the_official_Pi_2_image_on_the_Pi_3B.2F3B.2B-

Having flashed the SD card and edited the rest of the SD card as instructed, the Pi 3 B+ finally booted up. Not even stuck on the rainbow screen, it started running it's setup. But now is giving me new errors that I can't seem to find other resources on.

I've linked a couple images of the screen and how far it gets: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXNO6.jpg

My suspicion here is that I am still missing firmware regarding networking. In this case, my ethernet chip. This suspicion is reinforced here: [Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83734/ubuntu-mate-16-04-on-raspberry-pi-3-b)

And this is where I'm at. It even seems from that last link I should copy over some firmware for keyboard setup from Raspbian. However, even after copying the firmware and modules as instructed in the last link regarding Ubuntu Mate, I'm still getting the same network errors on boot up.

Has anyone managed to get ubuntu server 18.04 running on the raspberry pi?

Am I just making more work for myself and should have just stuck to Raspbian? In which case has anyone deployed a meteor app using MUP on raspbian stretch lite?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Cheers!

Comment: No the standard image is definitely not. That's why I used the raspberry pi 2 image as suggested by the Ubuntu wiki, "The official Raspberry Pi 2 images can be used with a Pi 3B/3B+ after minor changes".

So for someone who is trying to deploy meteor apps to a raspberry pi 3 b+ are there many other options or does meteor only deploy to ubuntu servers?

Comment: Uhm, isn't wifi optional if you never intend on using it? Even if I did want to install it the instructions are not specific. The wiki just states a bunch of wget commands without specifying where you should be placing them.

I was getting errors related to mongoDB and the container on the pi. I'll have to go back and reinstall that OS on the pi to get a pic of the error, but that'll be tomorrow. I just figured that raspbian wasn't configure by default to host meteor apps and thought I'd try an OS that works with meteor.

Have you successfully used MUP to deploy to raspbian yourself?

Comment: Yes and in order for MUP to work I need access to a network. The MUP thing was secondary because it is primary goal while the OS I'm using is Ubuntu because raspbian wasn't working with MUP. There is no Wifi in this setting so I am using ethernet. On boot up I posted pictures of the error I was getting in relation to the network, so if anyone who has successfully deployed meteor apps to a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ over MUP, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: I'll remove all my comments, as they haven't helped at all :p I'd still be tempted to follow the instructions you linked to fully - but that's just me

Comment: I would suggest that the fact there is no support for the major current Pi model 3B+ (by Ubuntu or 3rd party maintainers) - more than 6 months since its release indicates this is a waste of time. Many do not even support the Pi3 (18 months since release).

Comment: Is it possible this is because they're trying to push Ubuntu Snappy Core for IoT devices?

Answer (score -1):

update ethernet is running i think is only in my system imust make ifdown ifup

put this on your sdcard https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/

mount your sdcard to /media/root  /media/boot

you must run rpi-update

over usb

sudo curl -L --output /usr/bin/rpi-update https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update

sudo ROOT_PATH=/media/root BOOT_PATH=/media/boot rpi-update

and works

and 18.04

put this on your sdcard http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz

Change the bootloader

The official Ubuntu images use u-boot as the bootloader. The u-boot binary built for the Pi 2 does not work on the Pi 3 and this is why there are separate images for the Pi 2 and Pi 3. However, the Raspberry Pi has its own built in bootloader. This can be used with a few changes to the config.txt file on the system-boot partition.

Write the image to an SD card as normal, but before you insert it into the Pi mount the two partitions so that you can make changes. Open the config.txt on the first partition (labelled system-boot). Change the kernel line, add an initramfs line, and comment out (#) the device_tree_address line as follows:

kernel=vmlinuz
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

## device_tree_address=0x02000000

The second partition contains the Linux root filesystem. Copy the dtb file for your machine (e.g. bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb) plus the overlay folder if needed from /lib/firmware/4.X.X-XXXX-raspi2/device-tree to the system-boot partition.

For the Pi 3B+ you will also have to update the Pi bootloader files (bootcode.bin, fixup.dat and start.elf) on the system-boot partition.

sudo apt remove linux-firmware-raspi2
sudo cp /tmp/pi-bootloader/boot/* /boot/firmware/

If you are preparing an SD card on another machine, then mount the FAT formatted system-boot partition and copy the files across

sudo mount /dev/XXX1 /mnt
sudo cp /tmp/pi-bootloader/boot/* /mnt

wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/raspberrypi-bootloader_1.20180417-1_armhf.deb
dpkg-deb -x raspberrypi-bootloader_1.20180417-1_armhf.deb /tmp/pi-bootloader

Place the SD card in your Pi and turn on!

Update flash-kernel database

The flash-kernel package is used to copy the kernel and initrd to the fat system-boot partition.

sudo nano /etc/flash-kernel/db

Machine: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
DTB-Id: bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
U-Boot-Script-Name: bootscr.rpi3
Required-Packages: u-boot-tools
Boot-DTB-Path: /boot/firmware/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
Boot-Kernel-Path: /boot/firmware/vmlinuz
Boot-Initrd-Path: /boot/firmware/initrd.img
Boot-Script-Path: /boot/firmware/boot.scr

If you need to manually copy across the kernel and initrd files (note, the system-boot partition is mounted at /boot/firmware):

sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz /boot/firmware/
sudo cp /boot/initrd.img /boot/firmware/

flash-kernel

WLAN

wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.clm_blob
wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
sudo cp *sdio* /lib/firmware/brcm/
cd ..

FFMPEG MMAL VIDEO

apt install libmmx*

git clone  https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git

cd userland

./buidme

works

nice day