# change pi password on img before first boot, ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh, image, password

I want to be able to change the default pi:raspberry credentials *on the image* before first boot of a PiZero WH over the internet (phone hotspot, no home network). The default is a weak spot. I want to remove the vulnerability before the Pi hits the air (bad experience).

[David Maitland's protocol](https://medium.com/@DavidMaitland/raspberry-pi-zero-headless-setup-92fb72daf88d) to configure wifi networking and enable SSH works well for me.

However, I can't figure the password issue.

I've tried [mounting with offsets](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-can-i-mount-a-raspberry-pi-linux-distro-image) and `chroot` into the `rootfs`, but:

`x@flattest-clam:/media/x/ROOTFS$ chroot /media/x/ROOTFS passwd pi
chroot: cannot change root directory to '/media/x/ROOTFS': Operation not permitted
x@flattest-clam:/media/x/ROOTFS$ sudo chroot /media/x/ROOTFS passwd pi
chroot: failed to run command ‘passwd’: Exec format error
x@flattest-clam:/media/x/ROOTFS$ sudo chroot /media/x/ROOTFS /etc/passwd pi
chroot: failed to run command ‘/etc/passwd’: Permission denied`

Trying something similar with the image `dd`'d to SD card produced `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Exec format error`

I've seen posts that say this indicates the environment is different between host and target, (not entirely sure what that means, specifically).

On the other hand, another post suggested that `/bin/bash` requires libraries to work that may not exist on the target filesystem, so I tried and failed (my noob mistake I think in typing the command) to `cp /lib` and `/lib64` but it said it couldn't write and there was no space on the image (seemed odd).

I'm quite confused now - this is my first foray into chroot and I don't think I'm using it right. However, my objective is to change the password - that's the priority.

Is this a fool's quest? Is `chroot` the right way to go about it? Am I not setting permissions correctly (or at all, at the moment) - do I use my host or the Pi's credentials, btw?

Or does this all not work because `/etc/passwd` and its shadow are different and special?

Comment: Although the jist of the duplicate question is slightly different the solution is the same.

Comment: Although the answer on that duplicate question looks pretty good, I still need clarification: "On that system, create a new temporary user -- do all this via sudo or as root:" Fine, but am I doing this from just normal terminal as my usual desktop user, or chrooting into it? Sorry - noob and now quite confused.

Comment: No chroot.  Do it as if you were adding a new user to whatever system you use for this, then just copy the hash string into `/etc/shadow` on the SD card (or the mounted image before you copy to a card, but again: no chroot needed).

Comment: Likely the reason the chroot failed for you, BTW, is you were trying to do this from a normal desktop or laptop.  Those are pretty much all x86-64 [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).  Pi's are ARM based, which is 100% incompatible with that.  You can only run ARM software on an x86 machine if you do it in a hardware simulator such as QEMU (but don't bother chasing that path).